# How to keep keep NGINX reverse proxy from redirect away from localhost?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

So I have what seems to be a seemingly simple problem, but I am very new to this. I have set up a reverse proxy for my development environment, and I have have several machines that run different applications so I have them running on localhost with different ports obviously. Whenever I hit a location say `localhost/location1` and `localhost/location2` it does a proxy_pass to `localhost:8000` and `localhost:4343`. However, when I hit the root location seen below in my browser the url changes to the actual URL of the `proxy_pass https://develop.example.com/;` instead of just saying localhost which I would expect it to do like all the others do. So why does this change the URL? I have even tried doing a proxy pass to google which works as expected it just says localhost but shows a google 404 page. Any insights and or suggestions on how I can go about debugging this would be appreciated.

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Published-On https://develop.example.com/;

  proxy_pass https://develop.example.com/;
  #proxy_pass http://www.google.com/;

  index index.php;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the whole `server` section instead of a single `location`?

Comment: Why do you have index and proxy_pass directives? I suggest you edit your question to make it easier to understand, and add your full configuration.

Comment: It is most likely that your application is sending a redirect response back to the user, therefore you need to look at your application.

Comment: URLs containing "localhost" and "reverse proxy" are never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

[Add a `proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

```
proxy_redirect https://develop.example.com/ /;
```

This will rewrite the base url in the output from the proxy_pass so that links, etc., point back to the proxy.